# Sharepoint:ListFieldIterator - ExcludeFields property does not work

Tags: sharepoint

I've written a completely new page that uses Sharepoint's ListFieldIterator. I would like to exclude few fields from the view and I've found a solution using ExcludeFields but it simply doesn't work. The control always displays all fields, nevermind what's in ExcludeFields property. I couldn't find anyone complaining about such a problem on the internet.
There's the code (nothing fancy):

```
<Sharepoint:ListFieldIterator ID="lfiItemDetails" ControlMode="Display"  runat="server" ExcludeFields="TestId"  />
```

ListId and ItemId are set programmatically in OnInit.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a hash. So for the column I want to hide called "PrintOrder" I changed it from:

```
<SharePoint:ListFieldIterator ControlMode="Display" TemplateName="WideFieldListIterator" ExcludeFields="FileLeafRef;#WikiField" runat="server"/>
```

to

```
<SharePoint:ListFieldIterator ControlMode="Display" TemplateName="WideFieldListIterator" ExcludeFields="FileLeafRef;#WikiField;#PrintOrder" runat="server"/>
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else hits this. ExcludeFields dow not work if ControlMode is Display(at least on my version of. You need to either hide the field with Javascript or set ShowInDisplayform=False